MOSFET SSR inrush current with capacitive load
I'm searching for a small switch to switch 400 V AC 50 Hz on 11 nF capacitive load. Switch would not be opened and closed often and continuous current would be under 2 mA. 2 resistors were added before the switch to limit the inrush current to 280 mA in worst case scenario.

MOSFET SSR seems to be a good solution with low leakage current but I'm struggling to find one rated for peak 600 V and 300 mA. I found Broadcom ASSR-5211 (datasheet) but the maximum continuous current is 200 mA and there is no rating for peak current. Every other MOSFET SSR datasheet I've read also does not specify peak or inrush current (example from Vishay VOR1060M4).
Why are SSRs not rated for peak output current in the datasheet?
Maximum case temperature and output power dissipation is specified, should I use those in consideration for peak output current?
How can I be sure that the SSR wont burnout long-term?

Welcome! "Switch would not be opened and closed often" How about a regular mechanical relay?

There is not enough space for a regular mechanical relay.

How much space do you have available?

Why not use two of the Broadcom devices each in series with 2 kohm but, overall both circuits wired in parallel?

@winny space is very limited for this part of the circuit ( approx. 20x20mm) and i would like to keep it that way, otherwise i need to rearrange everything on the PCB. I plan to place SSR on the bottom side of the PCB so the smaller the better.

@Andyaka that is an interesting idea but i don't have much space on the PCB for 2 switches, and then I would need to trigger them at the exact same time.

@Burglups It's not homework, this is a real life problem I need to solve. Triac-SSR were considered but they leak too much current in off state.

13x29 mm is best I can do. What SSR can you fit in 20x20 mm?

@winny ASSR-5211 has a footprint of 10x10 mm, and VOR1060M4 is even smaller at 7x4.5 mm.

@Burglups Thanks, that looks promising. I'll look into it more, but I would still like to have my original question answered.

I see. Use two, one with inrush resistor and another one with straight connection? Turn on in sequence with some tens of ms of delay between them. Use only one with an NTC resistor?

@winny those are all good ideas but they are complicating a simple switch.

Then your only remaining options are a MOSFET SSR which can take the inrush current directly or an NTC resistor in series.
